# UIImage didnt show on my screen

Tags: objective-c

Following is my code. I can load all the image files from my NSMutableArray file but it didnt come out to my screen. I really dont know why. If anyone can help me with this would be really nice.

Thanks in advance.....

```
UIImageView *bannerImages;
    CGRect bannerFrame;

    for (int photoCount = 0; photoCount < [imagesFileList count]; photoCount++)
    {
        NSLog(@"photoCount: %d",photoCount);

        bannerImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 340, 320, 80)];

        NSString *photoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagesFileList objectAtIndex:photoCount]];

        NSLog(@"photoString are: %@",photoString);

        bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:photoString]];

        bannerFrame = bannerImages.frame;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                     animations:^{
                         bannerImages.frame = bannerFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];

    [self.view addSubview:bannerImages];
    [bannerImages release];
```

Here is my log file show:

```
2013-05-30 15:09:19.595 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoCount: 0
2013-05-30 15:09:19.596 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoString are: adv01.png
2013-05-30 15:09:19.596 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoCount: 1
2013-05-30 15:09:19.596 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoString are: adv02.png
2013-05-30 15:09:19.596 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoCount: 2
2013-05-30 15:09:19.596 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoString are: adv03.png
2013-05-30 15:09:19.597 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoCount: 3
2013-05-30 15:09:19.597 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] photoString are: edupro.png
2013-05-30 15:09:21.598 Yangon Guide Map[5035:15803] Done!
```

Comment: check if there are any other subviews blocking your image view in hierarchy..

Comment: its not blocking meera if I just load one image with exact name Eg. @"edupro.png" it show where I want to show. So its not hierarchy problem but thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: is it working now ? @Tin

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Assuming that the `.png` Images are in the `App Bundle`, you can replace

`bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:photoString]];` with

```
bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photoString]];
```

**2.** `bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;` dosen't seem to help.

Comment: Yap I already tried with bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photoString]]; but still the same it didnt load to my image view :)

Comment: where are the images placed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem what i think is that, you have populated the imageFileList with image names which you are getting while logging.

`imageWithContentsOfFile` is not supposed to get the image like this

**Try**

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:photoString ofType:@"png"]]];
```

**OR**

you can use the `imageNamed` methiod which is pretty strainght forward so instead of this

```
bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:photoString]];
```

**Use this**

```
bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photoString];
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do ? because their's a lot of errors in your code ...

1) You don't create your UIImage -imageWithContentsOfFile: will not find your file, use :

```
bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photoString];
```

or

```
bannerImages.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imageNamed:photoString stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:@"png"]];
```

2) You create a new UIImageView for each images in your array, but only add the last one to your root view. Add each of your UIImageView in you for loop :

```
for (int photoCount = 0; photoCount < [imagesFileList count]; photoCount++)
{
     bannerImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 340, 320, 80)];

     // Snip ...

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                 animations:^{
                     bannerImages.frame = bannerFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];

[self.view addSubview:bannerImages];
[bannerImages release];
}
```

3) Your bannerFrame calculation seems wrong too, because your are going out of your superview bounds, and all UIImageView will have the same frame. What is your superview, a UIScrollView ? What do you want to do ?